# boost serialization: see whether a stream is "good"

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization

I currently develop a server application which has to receive serialized data from clients, deserialize it and finally process it. The serialized data is sent in form of an array of chars. My problem is that my application can be easily broken by sending invalid data to it. So I wanted to ask whether it's possible to check a string(-stream) and see whether it's good for (de-)serialization (e.g. whether it has a valid signature) before trying to get data from it.

By the way: as the title already says, my application uses boost.serialization.

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you more interested in doing [Error detection and correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_detection_and_correction) or are you looking for something like [Message authentication codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_codes) ?

Comment: I think the error detection thing is what i'm looking for, because i'd like to prevent 'attackers' from breaking my software by sending wrong data and not checking whether the data has been somehow damaged on it's way to the server. And message authentication codes seem to work only if both sides (in this case: server and client) are interested in sending/receiving the right packets. (i mean, nothing prevents an atacker from sending a valid authentication code for his invalid data) . Thanks for the comment, I hope I understood everything correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to do a *lightweight* check, without requiring to read all data (in which case handling the exceptions is as efficient as it will get).

I just tested success with this simple function:

```
bool can_deserialize(std::istream& is)
{
    bool ok = false;
    is.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);

    try
    {
        boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(is);
        unsigned test = ia.get_library_version();
        ok = true;
    } catch (...) { }

    is.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);
    is.clear();
    return ok;
}
```

Here is a simple test harness that I used (manipulating the data in data.bin before deserialization to check for 'bad streams'):

```
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

bool can_deserialize(std::istream& is)
{
    bool ok = false;
    is.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);

    try
    {
        boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(is);
        unsigned test = ia.get_library_version();
        ok = true;
    } catch (...) { }

    is.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);
    is.clear();
    return ok;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> data = { 19415, -2611, 12092, -3942, -2535, 12105, 21079, 4660, 3,
        27131, 13647, 24428, 15159, 9029, 24827, -979, 17194, 25102, -3631,
        20914, -3223, 25801, 6652, 26208, -77, 15606, 8764, 1896, 7430, 24323,
        -152, 23805, -4259, 11243, 13367, 23559, 19293, 18581, 1639, 15671,
        7929, 18386, 5168, 13816, 465, 15801, 16750, -3340, -202, 10412, 11068,
        13458, 24304, 14814, 6530, 1178, -974, 12882, 757, 583, 4897, 24541,
        12490, -119, 2240, -4833, 569, 24700, 24522, 8708, 9760, 26837, 26060,
        20914, -3223, 25801, 6652, 26208, -77, 15606, 8764, 1896, 7430, 24323,
        3377, 6972, 25689, 2334, 1567, 21670, 23233, 14711, 4650, -4703, 25057,
        16057, 19488, 14575, 18936, 13346, 2779, 5644, 17165, 4526, 4390,
        9616, 2413, 14459, -1070, -4079, 22126, 9063, 4362, 8182, 24439, 23625,
        7929, 18386, 5168, 13816, 465, 15801, 16750, -3340, -202, 10412, 11068,
        4184, 25930, 24767, 2785, 17361, 18033, 12366, 20548, -3831, -4101,
        16841, -193, 23217, 6351, 19077, 23565, 10482, 4100, 27488, 15956,
        -2577, 7161, 20943, 25708, -2877, 7900, -4564, -3647, 12008, 1648,
        10533 };

    {
        std::ofstream ofs("data.bin", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ofs);

        oa & data;
        ofs.flush();
        ofs.close();
    }

    {
        std::ifstream ifs("data.bin", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
        if (can_deserialize(ifs))
        {
            std::cout << "OK! going to read..." << std::endl;

            boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(ifs);
            std::vector<int> cloned;
            ia & cloned;

            std::cout << "Read " << cloned.size() << " records" << std::endl;
        }
        else
            std::cout << "not OK! -- skipping data read" << std::endl;
    }

}
```