# How to detect invalid input using boost serialization?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, boost-serialization

I have a server which accepts client request. Client uses boost serialization to serialize data and Server deserializes data to get actual request.
Attacker might send fraud request to server. Server need to detect invalid input. The question is how?

```
  // client request
  char* input = ...;
  int size = ...;
  SomeType to_serialize;
  try {
    boost::iostreams::array_source source(input, size);
    boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::array_source> source_stream(
        source);
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive iarch(source_stream);
    iarch >> to_serialize;
  } catch (...) {
    ...
  }
```

Currently when receiving invalid request, the server might have to malloc up to 1.7TB memory. And OOM error occurs.

Comment: By writing code (you know, C++ code) that detects validity and sanity of input.

Comment: @ÖöTiib how? What type of input is valid for boost deserialization?

Comment: So put a sensible limit on allocations and abort the operation if that limit is exceeded.  Adding a checksum might be useful, if the invalid requests are accidental rather than hostile.

Comment: @ÖöTiib Do you know what boost serialization does? That feature doesn't exist

Comment: @sehe yes I know. What is the problem to write `if(x > limit) throw x_out_of_limit;` in `SomeType::serialize`?

Comment: @ÖöTiib the simple fact that you control none of that. Unless of course you suggest opting out of the builtin serializers. In which case you end up rewriting the library

Comment: Note that in "when receiving invalid request" I'm not assuming purposely invalid requests ("attacks") but also corruption due to receiving archives created with another version, another architecture, wire corruption or perhaps a transport protocol error. If that happens, basically Boost simply promises "undefined behaviour". So you need to embed in outside checks. You have a point though, the container serialization may not suit OP's requirements if they wish to guard against intentful DoS.

Comment: @SidS As sehe points out, allocating memory is inside boost serialization implementation and not exposed to user. I cannot perform the limit check.

Comment: Well, if a valid archive may exceed some limit, the only "outside" way I see is to have size-limited stream underlying the archive reader. That's a hack but is unlikely to lead to UB (IO errors are likely anticipated)

Comment: "Outside" checks about allocations inside  built in serializers of stock containers can be perhaps made by overriding standard allocators, providing custom allocators or by rewriting the library.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way. There's no real portable archive format in Boost.

You could use a 3rd party archive like [EOS Portable Archive](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=epa).

You'll still want to encode which version of the archive you're sending and check them explicitly before continuing into non-primitive deserialization functions.

Perhaps you can devise your own header to precede the archive stream¹. Depending on your payload you might be able to add a checksum after receiving the full stream as well.

If you need to receive in streaming mode (e.g. because the entire stream is too large to fit in memory, and you are building datastructures in mapped/shared memory?) and still want checksums, you could implement these at the underlying stream level. See https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html for inspiration.

Comment: Does the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7948623/486350 you provided solve my problem?

Comment: @tianyapiaozi It is a start. It assumes that a mismatch is detectable _and_ detected in the archive header. I'd suggest having outside checks  of your own so you can add your own checks even if the boost archive header would not trigger a fault there. (Or worse, in the event that the Boost input-archive header checks would invoke undefined behaviour)